# Get selected value instantly on listbox without clicking it first GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a listbox on my gui. When I start the programm the first value in the listbox is selected. But the programm only registers a value when you click it first. 
So is there a way the programm can start my calculation without having to click the first option in the listbox?

My idea was to set the handle in the Openingfunction, but it wont work out.

Here is my code:

```
function lastfolge_aufbereiten_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
...
...
guidata(hObject, handles);




function listbox_runden_stelle_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
contents=cellstr(get(hObject,'String'));
popupmenu_runden_stelle=contents(get(hObject,'Value'));
if (strcmp(popupmenu_runden_stelle,'10'))
    y=1;
elseif (strcmp(popupmenu_runden_stelle,'100'))
    y=2;
end
handles.y=y;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix (but not so pretty) could be to call you `listbox_runden_stelle_Callback` in the Openingfunction with the handle to your popup menu as input.

```
listbox_runden_stelle_Callback(handles.listbox_runden_stelle, [], handles)
```

---

A more general answer: You can use the `CreateFcn` that is executed when MATLAB creates the uicontrol (popupmenu). Below is a short example where both `CreateFnc` and `Callback` calls the a common evaluation function

```
function PopupMenu()

figure;
uicontrol(...
    'Style', 'popup', ...
    'String', {'Hello', 'World'}, ...
    'CreateFcn', @PopupMenuCreateFcn, ... 
    'Callback',  @PopupMenuCallback);

function PopupMenuCallback(hObject, ~)
disp('In Callback()')
PopupMenuEvaluate(hObject);

function PopupMenuCreateFcn(hObject, ~)
disp('In CreateFcn()')
PopupMenuEvaluate(hObject);

function PopupMenuEvaluate(popupMenu)
fprintf('Evaluated "%s" \n', popupMenu.String{popupMenu.Value})
```

(if you're using an older Matlab version you might have to replace "~" with an dummy string and the . (dot) operator with get(...) to get properties)

When running this, the `CreateFcn` is called upon directly, without the user selecting from the menu.

```
>> PopupMenu
In CreateFcn()
Evaluated "Hello"
```

If user then select 'World'

```
In Callback()
Evaluated "World"
```

If the same things is to be done for both `CreateFcn` and `Callback` you could just bind them to the same common function

```
uicontrol(...
    'Style', 'popup', ...
    'String', {'Hello', 'World'}, ...
    'CreateFcn', @PopupMenuEvaluate, ... 
    'Callback',  @PopupMenuEvaluate);
```

Comment: I tried your first quick fix and it worked but only for one listbox. If I add 3 of these commands for my 3 listboxes on my gui: `listbox_runden_stelle_Callback(handles.listbox_runden_stelle, [], handles);
listbox_auftrittswahrscheinlichkeit_Callback(handles.listbox_auftrittswahrscheinlichkeit, [], handles);
listbox_ausfallwahrsch_CreateFcn(handles.listbox_ausfallwahrsch, [], handles);
` it gives me the error **Reference to non-existent field 'y'.**

Comment: As the error says, `y` isn't created. Make sure that your the compare values in your `if`-`elseif` part truly are those in in the popup menu string ('10' and '100' in your example'). You should probably add a `else` in your callbacks, at least to through an error. Or start by adding a debug-point before the error-line.